# How does NTP Clock Discipline work?

Tags: logic, rfc, ntp

I was reading [NTPv4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) rfc to better understand the mechanism used by ntp. So, far the basic idea seems to be simple. But I am a bit confused regarding how [NTP Clock Discipline works](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905#section-11.3).

In NTPv4 it says a hybrid PLL/FLL is used to discipline the clock. According to my understanding - PLL locks on to the server phase and adjust client clock at update interval. FLL locks on to the clock frequency and adjusts the client clock at update interval.

it also says the PLL works better if there is more network jitter (latency spikes)
where FLL works better if clock wander is the issue (different clock frequencies / drift)

I can understand the use of feedback control to adjust them and can also understand how they are working from the diagram included in the NTP rfc. But can anyone explain how does NTP implements FLL/PLL hybrid clock discipline just from packet received from server?

It would be great if anyone can just explain the logic behind it also.

Comment: Read [Adaptive Hybrid Clock Discipline Algorithm
for the Network Time Protocol](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/database/papers/allan.pdf) or [NTP Clock Discipline
Principles](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/database/brief/clock/clock.pdf) by David L. Mills.

Comment: I tried reading both before posting the question but I couldn't understand the mechanism of FLL/PLL described on those references. I think rfc is more easier to digest than the paper & the presentation. Mainly because it uses 'reader-will-know-why-it-is-there' math. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try Prof. Mills' book?

Comment: @dfc sorry for late reply; Can you please mention the book's name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering exhaustively the question:

> How does NTP implements FLL/PLL hybrid clock discipline just from packet received from server?

requires the 90 pages of the document : [Network Time Protocol Version 4, Reference and Implementation Guide](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/database/reports/ntp4/ntp4.pdf). I will try to summarize an answer here.

In short, the NTP client receives timestamps from one or multiple servers and estimates a phase correction to apply. Then the correction is applied gradually in order to avoid clock jumps.

Both PLL or FLL can be used but the document says

> PLL usually works better when network jitter dominates, while
> a FLL works better when oscillator wander dominates.

Contrary to NTPv3, in NTPv4, PLL and FLL are used simultanouesly and combined.

**Feedback control system**

The clock discipline is implemented as the feedback control system shown in the figure 1.

[image]
Figure 1 : Clock discipline feedback loop

**theta_r** represents the reference phase generated by the combining algorithm and representing the best estimate of the system clock offset relative to the set of servers.

**theta_c** represents the control phase of the system clock modeled as a Variable Frequency oscillator (VFO).

**V_d** is the phase difference theta_r - theta_c

**V_s** is the output of the clock filter algorithm that select the best offset samples.

**V_c** is the signal produced by the loop filter which combines the PLL and the FLL as described in the second figure.

[image]
Figure 2 : Clock discipline loop filter

**=== Update ===**

To understand the details of phase offset and frequency offset computation, you have to dive into the reference implementation. A good point to start is the `packet()` function

```
/*
* packet() - process packet and compute offset, delay and
* dispersion.
*/
```

In broadcast server mode, the computation is as follow

```
offset = LFP2D(r->xmt - r->dst);
delay  = BDELAY;
disp   = LOG2D(r->precision) + LOG2D(s.precision) + PHI * 2 * BDELAY;
```

where `r` is the received packet pointer and `s` the system strucure.
Then the `clock_filter` function is invoked

```
/*
* The clock filter contents consist of eight tuples (offset,
* delay, dispersion, time). Shift each tuple to the left,
* discarding the leftmost one. As each tuple is shifted,
* increase the dispersion since the last filter update. At the
* same time, copy each tuple to a temporary list. After this,
* place the (offset, delay, disp, time) in the vacated
* rightmost tuple.
*/
```

The clock_filter itself invoke the `clock_select` function, and only after this the `clock_update` function is called.

What is important to remember is that these algorithms are synchronizing with multiple clocks and not with just one server clock. This introduce a layer of complexity and the question *How to synchronize with one server?* has no direct answer because algorithms are built to synchronize with multiple clocks.

The SNTP protocol (Simple NTP) use only one server clock but there is no official reference implementation.

Comment: My main issue was how it calculates the phase_offset & the frequency_offset in respect to a server. (Phase part is what you have written as V_d = (theata_r - theata_c). But how the frequency_offset is calculated? I have an idea; but not sure if it is right or wrong.
Anyways this answer will help anyone trying to understand NTP, so gj :)

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I know in the documentation it says SNTP can only sync to one server, but when I configured ntp on arch (installed this week following the installation guide) it led me to believe I was installing SNTP; yet it allowed me to configure multiple servers. Maybe this is because, as you say, there's no official reference implementation and the linux implementation chooses to allow multiple sources? Or maybe they just go to the next source in the list if there is a failure of some sort?

Comment: @Assimilater I think you should post a new question for this.

Comment: "Contrary to NTPv3, in NTPv4, PLL and FLL are used simultaneously and combined." If this is so, what is the meaning of the kernel status bit `STA_MODE` (defined in `timex.h`) ? It's a single bit, so it certainly looks like either/or. And the way it is shown by `ntpq -c kerninfo` also looks like either/or.